# how to find image links by using webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to parse the image links of webpages.I have tried the below code but its showing some error.

```
#!usr/bin/python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=raw_input("enter website")
r=requests.get("http://"+ url)
data=r.img
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print link.get('src')
```

error

```
File "img.py", line 6, in <module>
    data=r.img
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'img'
```

Comment: What is the error and which line is returning the error?

Answer (score 0):

you error is that you want to get `img` from `Response`, not from `source code`

```
r=requests.get("http://"+ url)
# data=r.img # it is wrong

# change instead of `img` to `text`
data = r.text # here we need to get `text` from `Response` not `img`

# and the code
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print link.get('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find a working version with `import urllib.request` and `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://python.org'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
  html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
  print('relative img path')
  print(link['src'])
  print('absolute path')
  print(url + link['src'])
```

I hope this helps you :-)